# How to implement change detection in angular when Spring changes data in the database

Tags: angular, spring, angular-changedetection

I would like to have a live reload(change detection) in Angular whenever Spring changes data in the database.(Spring will change data when it will be called through a rest endpoint from a database trigger)

How could I implement this change detection?

I am using Angular 5, Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible! You can just poll every X seconds.

Comment: Could you please show me an example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is every time I change something in the DB I also change a table\column with the last date of the changes to the DB

When your app start you get that date, after that you create a thread using:

> setInterval(function, delay)

the function should pulls the date from the DB and check if its the same,
If it's not the same then you update the app date and pull everything.

Later on you can check on conflicts in changes and so on for the user but that really depends on your app uses and implementation